# Etherchannel on 6509 (VSS) with interfaces from different type of modules supported?

Tags: cisco, cisco-6500

We currently have 1 10GB Multi-Chassis etherchannel Between 2x 6509 (VSS) and 2x 3750-E (Stack).

On the 6509 the etherchannel interface members currently run on the supervisor module VS-S720-10G.

We want to migrate that etherchannel over to a WS-X6704-10GE module, and was considering doing it in the following procedure:

- Shut down interface Te1/5/5 (member of etherchannel)
- Remove interface from etherchannel (no channel-group)
- Add interface from WS-X6704-10GE into etherchannel (Te1/3/4)
- Move fiber cable
- Redo same procedure for Te2/5/5 and Te2/3/4

When doing this we will for a short while have a etherchannel with members from different type of modules.
Is this supported by Cisco, or will this work at all?

Feel free to suggest other approaches to this migration...

Comment: I'd swap the order slightly: 1: add new interfaces into etherchannel, 2: move fibres, validating LACP on each one comes in (I do hope you're using LACP or at least PagP), 3: remove old interfaces from bundle.

Comment: it's LACP. 
This might be a "safer" way to do it...

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk389/tk213/technologies_tech_note09186a0080094714.shtml) documentation is a few years old but it does seem that only catch is that the links must be all set to the same speed.

Answer (score 1):

It works great on a 4500 and should work fine on a 6500.  The first answer was correct, though - the speed has to match and all links have to be full duplex.